# How to move duplicate lines from txt file and write to another?

Tags: .net, vbscript

I'm trying to read a txt file, take all the duplicate lines of the unsorted text file and write them to another txt file. I'm a beginner to programming so take it easy on me.

The code I have so far:

```
Options Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\A352592\Desktop\list01.txt", ForReading)

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do until objInputFile.atEndOfStream
    strCurrentLine = objInputFile.ReadLine
    If not Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) then 
        objOutputFile.WriteLine strCurrentLine
        Dict.Add strCurrentLine,strCurrentLine
    End if 
Loop
```

Example of what the text file looks like:

```
(1) = "example 4"
(1) = "example 6"
(1) = "example 4"
(1) = "example 2"
```

How would I remove the `(1) = "example 4"`line and write that to a new text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a second output file (you don't open the first output file in your code, BTW, so it should actually raise an error):

```
Set objOutputFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\output02.txt", 2, True)
```

and add an `Else` branch that handles the alternative case (line already is present in the dictionary):

```
If Not Dict.Exists(strCurrentLine) Then
  ...
Else
  objOutputFile2.WriteLine strCurrentLine
End If
```

Comment: I created a new question with your code and some new issues I'm having. Link to the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290115/wont-write-duplicate-lines-to-text-file